# How do I copy History items into the clipboard after Luna version?

Tags: eclipse

I have multiple versions of the Eclipse IDE installed, mostly because I have had trouble getting everything I need to work in later versions. The feature I cannot get to work in Mars or 'Photon' (2019-06) is very important to me, I need to cut/paste revision information (version number, date, author, and description) into a Jira for merges. The Copy menu item disappears after Luna.

[image: History Item Popup Menu]

Comment: How do I attach a screenshot? A picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: 2019-06 is not Photon, it is just 2019-06

Comment: You are talking about SVN, right? Do you use the [Subversive](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider) or [Subclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse) plug-in? In the current version of Subversive I can see the _Copy_ menu item. Maybe you switched from Subversive to Subclipse without noticing it.

Comment: I have Subclipse 4.3 installed. I don't see Subversive in the Eclipse Marketplace and the Subversive link you provided would not install saying it was not compatible. I am running Eclipse 2019-06, version 4.12 I think.

Comment: I see something similar that I could maybe use. The Generate ChangeLog option gives me the information to a file or clipboard but the formatting is going to make me do a lot of editing. Is there some way to configure that output like I can configure the commit text? I can't find it in the preferences but I have hard time tracking stuff like this down.